# How to read odd number of lines from a text file using Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a text file where each odd line holds an integer number (String ofcourse since its in a text file), even lines has a time. I only want to read the numbers, therefore the odd number of lines from a text file. How do I do that?

```
import java.io.*; 

public class File { 

BufferedReader in; 
String read; 
int linenum =12;


public File(){ 
try { 
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MAP_allData.txt")); 

for (linenum=0; linenum<20; linenum++){

read = in.readLine();
if(read==null){} 
else{
System.out.println(read);  }
}
in.close(); 
}catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("There was a problem:" + e); 

} 
} 

public static void main(String[] args){ 
File File = new File(); 
} 
}
```

As of now, it will read all the (odd and even) lines until there is not any more to read from (null)

Since my even number lines is a time stamp like `13:44:23` so can I do something like

> if(read==null OR if read includes a
>   time or semi colons ){}  else {
>   SOP(read);}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely putting a simple `in.readLine ()` just before the close of your `for`-loop will sort this out?

i.e.:

```
for (linenum=0; linenum<20; linenum++) {

    read = in.readLine();
    if(read==null){} 
    else{
        System.out.println(read);  
    }
    in.readLine ();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read in all lines, and ignore every other one.

```
int lineNum = 0;
String line = null;
while ( (line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
   lineNum++;
 if ( lineNum % 2 == 0 ) continue;
   //else deal with it
}
```

Or just call `readLine()` twice per loop, ignoring the second time, and avoid having a counter (safe since all calls to readLine return null after end-of-stream has been reached).

**Edit** If efficiency is absolutely key and the date lines had a fixed-length format, you could use `skip(15)` or similar to efficiently skip the lines you don't care about.

Comment: The indefinite `while` loop is a much better option than a `for`-loop!

Comment: @Philip: to be honest, I still typically use a for loop for this to scope `line` properly: `for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {...`  But your point is well made anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a linecounter, so if you want to use every other line, use the modulo check

```
if((linenum % 2) == 1){
     System.out.println(read);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just perform something like this each time you read in a line:

```
String str = read;
char[] all = str.toCharArray();
bool isInt = true;
for(int i = 0; i < all.length;i++) {
    if(!Character.isDigit(all[i])) {
        isInt = false;
    }
    else {
        isInt = true;
    }
}
if isInt {
    //INTEGER LINE
} else {
    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE TIME
}
```

This makes the code dynamic. If the text file changes, and integers appear on different numbered lines instead, your code can stay the same.

Comment: If the text file format changes, I'd want my code to break.  Who knows if it's actually the semantics that changed, in which case not breaking would lead to obscure bugs?

Comment: That's true.  If it were me and I were to take this approach, I'd probably favour passing the line to `Integer.parseInt()` or `Integer.valueOf()` and catching any `NumberFormatException`.  You're eventually going to want to do that anyway, to transform the input into a int/Integer. This way is verbose and fragile.  For instance, your method doesn't allow negative numbers.

Comment: I was thinking parseInt() with a try, catch, finally. That way is probably better.

Comment: Also, there's a subtle bug which makes it not work at all.  You should be breaking out of the loop after finding a non-digit.  With this implementation, as long as the last character is a digit, the whole input is considered an integer.  That probably wouldn't even distinguish it from most date formats.